# vim deleting backward tricks

Tags: vim

- How does one delete a word to the left? In other words, delete the word when the cursor stands at the end of it.
- How does one delete characters to the beginning of the line?
- How does one delete to the first whitespace to the left?
- **Any other tricks involving word deletion?**

Comment: There is no *two-keystroke* command to delete a word backwards when the cursor is on the last character of the word. For point #1 above, the best delete command is `dbx` or `bdw` when the word is at the end of the line (i.e., no whitespace follows). If changing the word instead, then `bC` works.

Comment: I use *vi command line editing* in my shell (`set -o vi`). Deleting or changing the last word of a previous command is very common, so I use `$dbx` and `$bC` often. If in *insert mode*, then `^w` will also delete words backwards.

Comment: When in Insert Mode, you can use <C-w> to delete words backwards.

Comment: `dvb`: https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/24wbuz/comment/chbbkfk/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Answer (score 229, accepted):

In general, d<motion> will delete from current position to ending position after <motion>. This means that:

1. d<leftArrow> will delete current and left character
2. d$ will delete from current position to end of line
3. d^ will delete from current backward to first non-white-space character
4. d0 will delete from current backward to beginning of line
5. dw deletes current to end of current word (including trailing space)
6. db deletes current to beginning of current word

Read [this](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#motion.txt) to learn all the things you can combine with the 'd' command.

Comment: Another handy shortcuts in case you find `db` hard to remember:


     `5. dw or d<ctrl+rightarrow>` and
     `6. db or d<ctrl+leftarrow>`

Comment: Rather than typing `d<leftArrow>` do `dh` instead, since `h` is the key for move left

Comment: Why is this accepted answer? d<leftArrow> (and non of the below except dw) will not delete a character under a cursor as OP wanted.

Comment: This is a very bad answer, as was already pointed out in the other comment, most of these won't delete the char under the cursor. This is also specifically stated in the linked docs.

Answer (score 99):

I have been in this scenario many times. I want to get rid of all the spaces in line 10 so it would join with line 9 after the comma.

[image]

This is basically a simple line join in VIM.

`kJ` does the trick (watch below)

[image: Vim Join Lines]

Comment: I have been looking everywhere for this!

Comment: Glad this was of help! You might want to check this one out too :-) http://stackoverflow.com/a/27542895/226255

Comment: haha, i want this and I have no idea how to describe it in Google. So lucky that i scroll down =))

Comment: Can't believe how many times I've done this manually. This is exactly what I was looking for, THANKS!

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. Vim blows my mind daily

Comment: The explanation for this is: `k` = Up, `J` = Join line below to the current one with one space in between. You could also do `kgJ` to join without a space. `gJ` = Join line below without space in between. Via cheatsheet: https://vim.rtorr.com/

Answer (score 48):

To answer point #3, `diw` and `daw` are excellent.

Comment: I find it sad that there are no two-character-commands to delete a word backwards when you're at the last letter, because in standard editors like notepad++, gedit etc. you can easily use CTRL+Backspace... except from that vim is excellent.

Comment: @Micha90, have you read the accepted answer? `db` does exactly that, and it's repeatable with `. `.

Comment: @roggan87 If you're on the last letter of a word, `db` deletes the letters preceding the last letter but still leaves the last letter.

Comment: Can you explain what the `i` and `a` are doing in the middle of those commands?  I know that the leading `d` is "delete", and I presume the trailing `w` is "word".

Comment: @CarlG The best explanation is in `:help text-objects`.  The leading paragraph is very concise and I think describes it very well.

Comment: <kbd>i</kbd> is "inner" and <kbd>a</kbd> is "a", as in "a word".  The former will not include enclosing whitespace, while the latter will include trailing whitespace, if any, otherwise will include preceding whitespace.  Very helpful, thank you.

Comment: @CarlG i = in, a = around

Comment: Use `ciw` and `caw` (`c` = "change" in place of `d` = "delete") to enter insert mode right away.

Comment: `diw` is better than `dvb`, in case anyone is wondering why the latter isn't here.

Answer (score 36):

In insert mode:

- ^w
- ^u
- can't answer out of my head ;-)

Otherwise:

- dw
- v0x
- can't answer out of my head ;-)

Comment: I didn't know that I can delete word in Insert mode in Vim. This helps a lot.

Answer (score 29):

In command mode:

1. `bdw`, back delete word.
2. `d^` (to the first non-blank), `d0` (to the first character)
3. `BdW` (go to first whitespace delete to next whitespace)

(Community wiki, feel free to hack.)

Answer (score 19):

**UPDATE: Seeing that many liked some of the additional tricks I've mentioned here, be sure to check the "Other (cool) boundaries section" at the bottom**

I feel that none of the answers is complete:

In general, you usually start a delete operation using `d<motion>`, and seldom using `x`.

> Note: When `N` is not specified, vim behaves as if `N=1` (deletes a single char)

**Discrete characters:**

`<N>x` - Delete N chars to the right

`d<N><left-arrow>` - Delete N chars to the left

`d<N><right-arrow>` - Delete N chars to the right

**Word boundaries:**

> Note: The 1st preceding/succeeding word is the one under the cursor

`d<N>b` - Delete from the beginning of the preceding N-th word to the current position

`d<N>e` - Delete from current position to the end of the succeeding N-th word

`d<N>w` - Same as `d<N>e` but **including trailing whitespace**

`diw` - Delete the entire word under the cursor

`daw` - Same as `diw` but **including trailing whitespace**

**Line boundaries:**

`d0` - Delete from the beginning of the line to the current position

`d^` - Delete from the first non-whitespace char to the current position

`d$` - Delete from the current position to end of line

**Other (cooler) boundaries:**

These are tricks even veteran vim users usually don't know of, but are probably some of the most powerful tools in vim.

`di(` or `di)` - If you are located anywhere inside a parenthesis scope, i.e. `(int a, int b, int c)`, deletes everything between the parenthesis, and leaves `()`. Very useful when changing function prototypes, conditions, loops, etc.

`di{` or `di}` - Same as the one above, but deletes everything inside a curly brace scope. Very useful for changing a method implementation easily.

`di[` or `di]` - You get the point, right? ;)

`dit` - Delete contents of a tag. For example, given `<a href="..."><img src="smiley.gif"></a>`, if you place you cursor within the `<a...>` tag and press `dit`, it will delete the entire `<img...>` part (Thanks @Eric for mentioning that).

**Other important hint[s]:**

Just in case you didn't know that, every sequence that starts with `d` can be replaced with `c` to delete and then go straight into insert mode!

Comment: This is in fact the most complete answer as it explicitly touches on deleting the entire word under cursor with `diw` and `daw`. Very useful commands!

Comment: `dit` is another useful one. Deletes the inside of an xml/html tag.

Answer (score 16):

1. `db` (if the cursor is after the word) or `bdw`
2. `d0` (or `d^` if you want to delete to the first non-blank character)
3. `dE` or <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to delete to the first space or <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to delete to the next white space character.

**Edit**

Since the question has been changed such that 3 is delete to the first whitespace character 
to the left, my answer should change to:

3. `dB` or <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to delete back to the first space or <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>?</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to delete to the previous white space character.

See:

```
:help motion.txt
:help WORD
```

Comment: Good call on #3.  I wasn't sure how to handle ANY whitespace.  It's worth mentioning that dF<SPACE> will delete up to and including the <SPACE> while dT<SPACE> will leave the <SPACE> there.

Comment: Came here looking for something like `bdw`. The remaining character (the one originally under the cursor) of `db` kept annoying me.

Answer (score 4):

Two of my favorite vi delete commands are:

`dt<char>` deletes up to the 
`dT<char>` deletes backwards up to the

These are particularly useful for working with punctuation but can also be used for pretty quick word deletion by using `dt<space>` or `dT<space>`.

Answer (score 3):

`db` Deletes backward to the end of the word, but it does leave the character under the cursor.
So if your cursor is at the last character of the word, `db` will delete all of it except the last character.

To also delete the character under the cursor, you can remap `db` into `ldb`, which moves the cursor right before deleting, thus also catching that last bit.

```
nnoremap db ldb
```

It works great, *unless* there is a space after the cursor's original position (this space will be left).

Another option is using `dge` that deletes backward to the end of word - but since it's an inclusive motion, it also deletes the 1st character of the previous word.

`daw` Handles all the spaces and surrounding words well, but will always delete the entire word you're on - even if not on the last character.

The best solution I have found is writing my little script which smartly handles things:

```
" Map db and dB to using the function
" Allows a smarter db
nnoremap db :call DeleteBackWord(0)<CR>
" Allows a smarter dB
nnoremap dB :call DeleteBackWord(1)<CR>

function! DeleteBackWord(capital_mode)
  " Gets the character after the cursor
  let l:next_char = getline(".")[col(".")]
  " Check if it's a whitespace
  if l:next_char !~# '\S'
    " whitespace, delete around word
    if a:capital_mode == 0
      call feedkeys('daw', 'n')
    else
      call feedkeys('daW', 'n')
    endif
  else
    " NOT whitespace, go 1 char right, then delete backward
    if a:capital_mode == 0
      call feedkeys('ldb', 'n')
    else
      call feedkeys('ldB', 'n')
    endif
  endif
endfunction
```

This code even differentiates deleting words and WORDS.

Answer (score 2):

`/ <CR>x`

(search forward for a space, hit enter to go there, x to delete)

There may be a more magic way of doing it, but I don't know of one.

Comment: If you want to delete the first whitespace to the left, hit ? instead of / in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Was looking for this, great answers, here are two more tricks guys:

1. `vbd` or `vbx` - visual back delete
2. `vbc` - visual back change

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 inoremap <C-w> <C-o>diw
```