# How do I paste a column of text after a different column of text in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have two columns full of text, and I want to get them side-by-side. For example, I have

```
abc
def
ghi
```

and

```
123
456
789
```

and I want

```
123 abc
456 def
789 ghi
```

All I can find is how to paste the *same* line onto the end of every line in a column. I can't figure out how to paste a multi-line block of text on the end of another column.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use visual block (`ctrl-v`) to cut the letter column. Then move to the first line of the number column. Move to the end and make one space. Then paste the letter column.

Comment: Is there something special about cutting/yanking while in visual block mode? My problem right now is the register I'm using is actually the `*` register, which means the system clipboard.

Comment: The same register is being used for plain `y` and `p`, if you're not specifying a special one with `"`.

Comment: I find this nice plugin by Ingo Karkat helpful when wanting to "cast" a paste. http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355

Comment: @kevin: if you use `"*x`, then you paste with `"*p`. There should not be any problem emerging from using visual blocks. Hopefully you have got `+xterm_clipboard` "incompiled".

Comment: @clime: The implication here is that cutting from a blockwise visual selection is different than cutting from a linewise visual selection (although I don't see any indication of this in `:registers`). The problem is that the `*` register is the system clipboard (I'm in MacVim) and therefore I have no control over the linewise-vs-blockwise nature of this register (e.g. it's always linewise).

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it carries the implication that I just mentioned, that a blockwise cut is different than a linewise cut, but I would appreciate a pointer to documentation on this subject since I cannot find it while looking through the vim help.

Comment: I know it's in there somewhere — Vim is supposed to store metadata about the copied thing that doesn't appear when pasting. I recently ran into it. I'll see if I can find it again.

Comment: Ah, I think I remember it from here: it's mentioned under help for ‘gui-selections’ (probably elsewhere aswell). [quote from help]

„Note that when pasting text from one Vim into another separate Vim, the type of selection (character, line, or block) will also be copied.  For other applications the type is always character.“

Comment: @kevin: "I have no control over the linewise-vs-blockwise nature of this register (e.g. it's always linewise)." So you are saying that the operation I described won't work on macs? Interesting...

Comment: @MatejNanut: That's helpful. I also finally found information on blockwise registers, under the help name `blockwise-register`

Comment: @clime: If I copy from a blockwise selection in MacVim, then go to a different instance of MacVim, it retains the blockwise nature. But if I copy from another application (which is what I did), it doesn't. I had to paste into vim, then do a blockwise selection and re-copy, in order to get a blockwise registers to use.

Comment: This is a thing of beauty.  vim just saved me from individually copying and pasting dozens of lines of code.

Comment: I literally did not realize I was hitting Shift-V and going into LINE visual mode instead of Control-v and going into BLOCK visual mode. They are two different things!

Comment: What if you want to put the letter column on the left of the number column?

Answer (score 115):

I was wondering why "visual block mode" wasn't working for me. The key is to **yank** (or delete) in visual block mode.

I find myself needing to copy some stuff from excel columns having variable lengths. Here's how I do it:

```
Names
Donald Knuth
Sebastian Thrun
Peter Norvig
Satoshi Nakamoto

Age
100
50
60
45
```

Let's say you want to put the second column after the first.

1. Yank it in visual block mode:

- Move cursor to the beginning of `Age`
- Press `Ctrl + v` to enter visual block mode
- Move cursor to `5` in `45`
- Press `y` to yank (or `d` to delete)

You have now yanked in visual block mode.

2. Paste (in normal mode)

- Move to the end of the first line and add more spaces because it's shorter than the second line for example. If you paste a "block" without adding extra spaces, it will overwrite the "run" in Sebastian Thrun.
- Now you're on the first line, insert a few spaces after the last character. Make sure you're not in insert mode and hit `p` to paste the block. (If you want to paste in insert mode, use `ctrl+r "`)

[image]

Comment: @Abdo: Thanks, this helped me. However, although pasting in normal mode works as expected, inserting with `ctrl+r "` does not work as described. Is that how it should be?

Comment: @Xiphias type `:registers` and see what you have in there. If you do have something under `"` , you're probably typing `ctrl+r '` (make sure you're holding the shift)

Comment: Actually, it is called "Visual Block Mode", not just "Visual Mode".

Comment: DUDE.....Dude.....dude. This is so useful. However, if data (the stuff selected in visual mode) is also uneven--particularly if a middle row has more characters (+1 for end-of-line) than those at the top (or bottom depending on where you started the selection)--then the full selection cannot be made. The trick is to add spaces to the end of the shorter cursor line until the offset matches that of the longest line. e.g. try `1\n100\n1` and the last `0` of `100` will be missing.

Comment: @JonathanKomar I did mention adding the spaces above and I did represent it in my animated image =)

Comment: Just a quick note that for me this doesn't work if I have `set clipboard^=unnamed` in my `vimrc` to automatically share the clipboard between macOS and Vim. With that option set, it always pastes the contents as a single column, with that option removed, the paste works as described above.

Comment: @robenk thanks for sharing! I was wondering why it stopped working for me :-)

Comment: It seems that `<C-r><C-o>"` must be used instead of `<C-r>"` to paste block in insert mode.  Also, in the example, you may cut Names column and insert before Ages column instead (at Names `<C-q>jjjj$A gvx`, then at Age `P`.

Comment: VSVim is an emulator and is does not support all of VIM's features

Comment: pasting in normal mode with p works however I couldn't make it work in insert mode with ctrl-r " combination.

Comment: I found it a bit easier to pad out the left column (in my case, 2-3 character alphanumeric codes followed by a colon) with spaces, then ctrl-V and select/yank them all in one rectangle, then paste them to the left of the second column (just go to start of the top line and hit p).

Comment: agreed with @Fritz, I tried this the first time as suggested with visual mode and didn't work. If possible, recommend editing to make the answer correct. I.e. write 'visual block mode' instead of 'visual mode' :)

Answer (score 21):

If you're on a Mac and can't figure out why the paste is inserting the block in new lines, it's because you're using the system pasteboard.

No problem, just yank/paste with buffers:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> - select what you want to yank
2. <kbd>"</kbd>*letter*<kbd>y</kbd> - yank into `letter` buffer
3. Go to where you want to paste
4. <kbd>"</kbd>*letter*<kbd>p</kbd> - paste from `letter` buffer

Make sure that `letter` is not `+` as that is the system pasteboard buffer and thus it will have the same effect.

Comment: This is the answer for me. The system pasteboard, ie. `+` register , don't let `p` to paste column.

Comment: Thanks! By far, the best answer.

Comment: Vim newbie.. what is `"` _letter_ `y`?

Comment: @Ben: Vim has the concept of named buffers, namely one for many of the ASCII characters. `"` is the buffer selector start, followed by some letter (denoting a buffer name, e.g. `a`), and `y` means to "yank" (copy). Since the `y` is prefixed with the buffer selector, the copied data will be placed in that buffer instead of the default buffer. You can then use a buffer selector sequence to paste afterward.

Answer (score 16):

You have:

```
abc
def
ghi

123
456
789
```

Move your cursor onto the `a`. Then `CTRL+V`, and move your cursor to `i`. Press `y`.

Next, add a space after the `3` character, and press `p`.

Done.

Answer (score 8):

This may seem obvious, but if you are pasting from an externally copied buffer it will not work with just visual mode paste. What you can do is first do a normal paste in an empty area and vertical cut/paste using the above method.

Comment: Yes! This was exactly my problem. Thanks for pointing it out! If you have used system clip board for your normal pasting, make sure to paste with another register to achieve the block paste effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to manually set the register type to say blockwise, use this

```
:call setreg(0, getreg(0), 'b')
```

or

```
:call setreg('*', getreg('*'), 'b')
```

Useful for pasting a column from a spreadsheet editor.

See `:help setreg` and [vimtip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Unconditional_linewise_or_characterwise_paste) for details.

Answer (score 0):

If your columns are different lengths and it is cumbersome to align them to use the blockwise copy and paste, you can search-and-replace while getting rows from the clipboard.

For the rows in the most upvoted answer:

```
Names
Donald Knuth
Sebastian Thrun
Peter Norvig
Satoshi Nakamoto
```

you can do `:'<,'>s/$/\=getreg('"',1,1)[line("'<")-line('.')]`, which substitutes end-of-line with the contents of the default register indexed (linewise) by start-of-visual-selection `'<` minus the line number the substitution is happening on `.`.

This would result in `NamesAge` etc., so to also add a space, you can join strings in vim with `.`. `:'<,'>s/$/\=' '.getreg('"',1,1)[line("'<")-line('.')]` gives you

```
Names Age
Donald Knuth 45
Sebastian Thrun 60
Peter Norvig 50
Satoshi Nakamoto 100
```

This is of course more useful for more complex cases, like substituting keys in dictionaries of key-value pairs.