# How to join a bunch of lines in VI

Tags: sed, vi

I have 2 bunch of lines in VI (shown below)

```
NET1_FT_IN_0_REL2
NET2_FT_IN_0_REL2
NET3_FT_IN_0_REL2
NET4_FT_IN_0_REL2
NET5_FT_IN_0_REL2
NET6_FT_IN_0_REL2

NET1_FT_OUT_0_REL2
NET2_FT_OUT_0_REL2
NET3_FT_OUT_0_REL2
NET4_FT_OUT_0_REL2
NET5_FT_OUT_0_REL2
NET6_FT_OUT_0_REL2
```

I want to join them like how its shown below. Can anyone help how to get this done in VI.

```
NET1_FT_IN_0_REL2 NET1_FT_OUT_0_REL2
NET2_FT_IN_0_REL2 NET2_FT_OUT_0_REL2
NET3_FT_IN_0_REL2 NET3_FT_OUT_0_REL2
NET4_FT_IN_0_REL2 NET4_FT_OUT_0_REL2
NET5_FT_IN_0_REL2 NET5_FT_OUT_0_REL2
NET6_FT_IN_0_REL2 NET6_FT_OUT_0_REL2
```

Comment: The Unix `paste` command is your help here.  Save the first segment into file `f1`; save the second segment into file `f2`; capture the output of `paste f1 f2` in your original file.  (Use `paste -d ' ' f1 f2` if you want a space between the columns instead of a tab.) . Do you know enough `vi` to be able to do that, or do you need a keystroke by keystroke account of what to do?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried it out; I see that the contents of f1 & f2 are spaced apart by 1 tab space by using the paste cmnd but ,I need only a single character space b/n them...

Comment: My updated comment says how to get blanks instead of tabs with `paste`.  You could also do a global search and replace for tabs with blanks, couldn't you?

Comment: yes. .I can replace tabs with space... just wanted to know how to get it done with paste cmnd itself. Thank you.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120552/how-do-i-paste-a-column-of-text-after-a-different-column-of-text-in-vim/9120598

Comment: @gregory: It's interesting that your suggested alternative question gives a totally different way of doing it, one that I presume works.  I've not bothered to learn visual block modes; it wasn't part of `vi` when I learned `vi` (AFAICR — we're delving back into the mists of yesteryear).

Answer (score 0):

The Unix `paste` command is your help here. Save the first segment into file `f1`; save the second segment into file `f2`; capture the output of `paste f1 f2` in your original file. (Use `paste -d ' ' f1 f2` if you want a space between the columns instead of a tab.) . The `paste` command can combine more than 2 files if need be.

A key sequence (one of many possibilities) that would do the job on the 13 line file shown in the question is:

- `:1,6w f1` <kbd>return</kbd>
- `:8,13w f2` <kbd>return</kbd>
- `:1,$!paste -d ' ' f1 f2` <kbd>return</kbd>

For a completely different view on how to do it using visual blocks (are those a part of `vi` or only a part of `vim` — and does the difference matter these days?), see:

- [How do I paste a column of text after a different column of text in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120552/)