# How to merge two list and make a dictionary using vim in vscode?

Tags: list, dictionary, vim, visual-studio-code, merge

Imagine we have two list in two files, 
file 1: contact_list_names.txt  like:

```
Ali
James
Amir
Jones
Sarah
```

file 2 :contact_phones.txt like:

```
12344
43211
09876
67890
12309
```

I know that we can select all using `gg` then `v` then `Shift + g` to select all , but when you paste using `p` key its not pasting every number in front of its contact name ...
So how to paste the numbers in front of its related contact name ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem using the clipboard to paste columns side by side is the type of selection of it, see here:

```
:echo getregtype('+')

if it returns a lowercase v, it means the type is characterwise.
if it returns an uppercase V, it means the type is linewise.
if it returns ^V{some number}, it means the type is blockwise, and the width of the block is {some number}.
```

But we can change it this way (making the clipboard register blockwise):

```
:call setreg('+',@+,'b')
```

Now if you try to paste a new column before or after the first one 
you will succeed!

Here a function to get the content of the clipboard and paste after 
the current column

```
fun! GiveItaNameYouWant()
    call setreg('+',@+,'b')
    normal gg
    execute "normal! A \<esc>"
    execute "normal! \"+p"
endfun
```

If you copy this function to the clipboard and load it into the memory just run:

```
:@+
```

Now put the cursor at the first column and run:

```
:call GiveItaNameYouWant()
```

Note: I am referring only to the clipboard register but you can also make these changes on the primary register selection "*", in the yank register "0" and default register '"' and a-z ones.

References: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48678100/2571881